# Draw a geometric shape

Tags: delphi, drawing, delphi-2006

I am trying to draw/display a geometric shape on a Delphi form given a list lines and arcs at a specific X and Y (Cartesian).

Example:

```
-Line X0Y0 to X10Y0
-Line X10Y0 to X10Y10
-Line X10Y10 to X0Y10
-Line X0Y10 to X0Y0
-Arc/Circle at X5Y5 diameter of 1
```

Would draw a 10x10 square with a 1 unit diameter hole in the center. How can I draw this on a form?

I am trying to use this article has a referece, but is there are better ways to do this?
[http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/CodeExamples/XE4/en/FMXTCanvasDrawFunctions_(Delphi)](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/CodeExamples/XE4/en/FMXTCanvasDrawFunctions_%28Delphi%29)

Comment: I think it is a VCL form in Delphi 2006. I haven't tried anything because I have no idea what to try. I've never done anything like this. I don't know what component to add to my form to allow me to start something.

Comment: You want to draw lines and arcs. You've found example code of *built-in* functions that draw lines and arcs. Where is the problem?

Comment: @ikathegreat, you should do `TCanvas.MoveTo` and `LineTo` for all of your line segments.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In a new VCL Form application (`File->New->VCL Form Application`), drop a `TButton` in the middle of the form, double-click it to create a `TForm1.Button1Click` event handler, and use this code:

```
procedure TForm1.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
var
  OldBrushColor, OldPenColor: TColor;
begin
  // I've enlarged the size of the rectangle (box)
  // to 20 x 20 for illustration purposes.
  OldBrushColor := Self.Canvas.Brush.Color;
  Self.Canvas.Brush.Color := clBlack;
  Self.Canvas.Rectangle(10, 10, 30, 30);
  Self.Canvas.Brush.Color := OldBrushColor;
  Self.Canvas.Ellipse(11, 11, 29, 29);

  // Alternative using MoveTo/LineTo and
  // changing pen color
  OldPenColor := Self.Canvas.Pen.Color;
  Self.Canvas.Pen.Color := clRed;
  Self.Canvas.MoveTo(30, 10);
  Self.Canvas.LineTo(50, 10);
  Self.Canvas.MoveTo(50, 10);
  Self.Canvas.LineTo(50, 30);
  Self.Canvas.MoveTo(50, 30);
  Self.Canvas.LineTo(30, 30);
  Self.Canvas.MoveTo(30, 30);
  Self.Canvas.LineTo(30, 10);
  Self.Canvas.Ellipse(31, 11, 49, 29);

  Self.Canvas.Pen.Color := OldPenColor;

end;
```

Sample of the above:

[image: Screen capture image]

You can find other `TCanvas` drawing methods (such as `Arc`, `Chord`, and the combination of `MoveTo` and `LineTo` in the [documentation](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/XE4/en/Vcl.Graphics.TCanvas). (The link is for XE4's docs, but the Delphi 2006 documentation should have the info as well.)